# override Task from Interface

Tags: c#, overriding

Let say that I have such as Interface:

```cs
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IDto, new()
{
...
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllComplexAsync() =>
        await GetAllComplexAsync(o => true);

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllComplexAsync(
        Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpr,
        bool descending = false) =>
       await GetAllComplexAsync(o => true, orderByExpr, descending);

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllComplexAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpr) =>
       await GetAllComplexAsync(whereExpr, o => true);

    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllComplexAsync(
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpr,
            Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpr,
            bool descending = false);
}
```

then I'm implementing it in generic method:

```cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class, IDto, new()
{
...
    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllComplexAsync(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> whereExpr,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByExpr,
        bool descending = false) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

which this need to be override in repository, but here I get error:
"no suitable method found to override"

```cs
public class SupplierRepository : GenericRepository<SupplierDto>
{
...
    public override async Task<IEnumerable<SupplierDto>> GetAllComplexAsync()
        {
            return await _context.Suppliers
           .AsNoTracking()
           .Include(o => o.MachineTypes)
           .ToListAsync();
        }
}
```

I wan to use generics for most tasks, but some of them are more complex (like including, etc.), thats why I want to override them in final class.

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That method must be declared as `public async Task<IEnumerable<SupplierDto>> GetAllComplexAsync()` without the `override` since it's not `virtual`; it's just an interface implementation.

Comment: @pfx - thank you, I didn't try that.
should I keep virtual in Interface then or not?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a new C# 8 feature called default interface methods. Unlike what most people expect, the class that implements the interface does not inherit the interface's default implementation of that method.  This is explained in the [C# 8 Feature documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#concrete-methods-in-interfaces).

As a consequence, the `GenericRepository` class does not have the `GetAllComplexAsync()` method you are trying to override in your `SupplierRepository`.

We can demonstrate this as follows:

```
IGenericRepository<SupplierDto> x = new GenericRepository<SupplierDto>();
//this will work, and will use the interface's implementation
var result = await x.GetAllComplexAsync();

GenericRepository<SupplierDto> y = new GenericRepository<SupplierDto>();
//this will not compile, as the GenericRepository does not have that method 
var result2 = await y.GetAllComplexAsync();
```